# komapping.toJS doesn't map nested observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have JSON coming as nested arrays as follow

```
   [
                  {
                    "Amount": 3250,
                    "CustomerAccountNumber": 1,
                    "EntityName": "a",
                    "Id": 1,
                    "IsValidationSuccess": false,
                    "IsWorkInProgress": true,
                    "ValidationErrors": [
                      {
                        "CreationDate": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
                        "Reason": "Error1"
                      },
                      {
                        "CreationDate": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
                        "Reason": "error2"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Amount": 450,
                    "CustomerAccountNumber": 1,
                    "EntityName": "s",
                    "Id": 4,
                    "IsValidationSuccess": false,
                    "IsWorkInProgress": true,
                    "ValidationErrors": [
                      {
                        "CreationDate": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
                        "Reason": "error"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Amount": 5600,
                    "CustomerAccountNumber": 2,
                    "EntityName": "f",
                    "Id": 2,
                    "IsValidationSuccess": false,
                    "IsWorkInProgress": true,
                    "ValidationErrors": [
                      {
                        "CreationDate": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
                        "Reason": "error"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
```

- then I group by customer no and entityEntityName and populate model observable array using Which gives me following JSON

  ```
   [
    {
      "Count": 2,
      "CustomerAccountNumber": 1,
      "Entities": [
        {
          "Count": 1,
          "Entity": [
            [object Object]
          ],
          "EntityName": "a",
          "Sum": 3250
        },
        {
          "Count": 1,
          "Entity": [
            [object Object]
          ],
          "EntityName": "b",
          "Sum": 450
        }
      ],
      "Sum": 3700
    },
    {
      "Count": 1,
      "CustomerAccountNumber": 2,
      "Entities": [
        {
          "Count": 1,
          "Entity": [
            [object Object]
          ],
          "EntityName": "c",
          "Sum": 5600
        }
      ],
      "Sum": 5600
    }
  ]
  ```

  and then when I need back in JS then TOJs is not mapping nested arrays but model binding in html with knockout binds data properly.

```
komapping.toJS(viewModel.result())
```

give me following result - it doesn't map nested array , is there any way we can fix this ?

update

```
viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.transactionLines = ko.observableArray();
    self.result = ko.observableArray();

}
```

After AJAX Load I am pushing object to observableArray after grouping

```
        var byAccountNo = groupBy(data, function (item) {
            return [item.CustomerAccountNumber];
        });

        _.each(byAccountNo, function (item) {
            var byEntity = groupBy(item, function (i) {
                return [i.EntityName];
            });

            var obj = {
                CustomerAccountNumber: item[0].CustomerAccountNumber,
                Entities: ko.observableArray()
            };

            _.each(byEntity, function (itemEntity) {

                var objByEntity = {
                    EntityName: itemEntity[0].EntityName,
                    Entity: ko.observableArray()
                };

                _.each(itemEntity,
                    function (inner) {
                        var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(inner);
                        self.transactionLines.push(result);
                        objByEntity.Entity.push(result);
                    });

                objByEntity.Sum = ko.pureComputed({
                    read: function () {
                        var total = 0;
                        _.each(objByEntity.Entity(), function (item) {
                            total += item.Amount();
                            });
                        return total;
                    },
                    owner: objByEntity
                });


                objByEntity.Count = ko.pureComputed({
                    read: function () {
                        return objByEntity.Entity().length;
                    },
                    owner: objByEntity
                });

                obj.Entities.push(objByEntity);
            });

            obj.Sum = ko.pureComputed({
                read: function () {
                    var total = 0;
                    _.each(obj.Entities(), function (item) {
                        total += item.Sum();
                    });
                    return total;
                },
                owner: obj
            });

            obj.Count = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    var total = 0;
                    _.each(obj.Entities(), function (item) {
                        total += item.Count();
                    });
                    return total;
                },
                owner: obj
            });


            self.result.push(obj);
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `ko.mapping.toJS()` [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), this is not suprising:

> This will create an unmapped object containing only the properties of
>   the mapped object that were part of your original JS object. So in
>   other words, any properties or functions that you manually added to
>   your view model are ignored

I think you may want to try `ko.toJS()` or `ko.toJSON()` instead of `ko.mapping.toJS()` if you are looking at exporting the object.

See [documentation for `ko.toJS()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

Comment: everything in this object created manually only still it maps everything except Entity nested array. ko.js doesn't work either and toJSON will give string which I don't want.

Comment: @JitendraAanadani you need to provide more code. How do you modify your data? How is your `viewModel` defined?